# Delete subjects which isn't selected anymore

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to edit subjects which isn't selected by student anymore. This is how my db looks like:
[image]

Using `editStudent` query I'm selecting items which is edited and using `studentSubject` I'm retrieving subjects from db.

```
var editStudent = (from st in _db.Students
                                   where st.Id == student.Id
                                   select new Students
                                  {
                                      Id = student.Id,
                                      Name = student.Name,
                                      Surname = student.Surname,
                                      BirthDate = student.BirthDate,
                                      Gender = student.Gender,
                                      Subject = (from q in student.Subject
                                                 select q).ToList()
                                  }).FirstOrDefault();

var studentSubjects = (from q in _db.Subjects
                                       where q.StudentId == student.Id
                                       select q.Name).ToList();
```

How can I delete subjects which isn't selected anymore? (They will no long be in Subject list from first query)

For example:

> in db was 2 subject math and english and user changed these and now he
>   has only math. first query will return only math in list and second
>   will return both math and english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily select not used Subjects with

```
var subjectsNotUsed = _db.Subjects.Where(subject => subject.StudentId == null);
```

Then (if you are using Entity Framework 6) you can use `.RemoveRange()` so:

```
_db.Subjects.RemoveRange(subjectsNotUsed);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

If you use lower version of EF, you need to delete one by one:

```
foreach (var subject in notUsedSubjects)
{
    _db.Subjects.DeleteObject(subject);
}
_db.SaveChanges();
```

But I think you should change the database schema. Student shouldnt be related to Subject. You should use table **Students** just for information about students, and table **Subjects** just for subjects. Third table (basic M:N relation) you will represent that student has some subject, like that:

[DB Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFN2S.png)

This enables you store each subject and student just once in your database.